# QML calendar not working with S4

Tags: qml

I have tried my app in Samsung Galaxy S4 and for some reason the calendar doesn't open in the correct day and the Month at the top doesn't show the correct month. 
It works in my laptop and also in my Nexus4. Therefore,  it seems to be a problem with the Galaxy phones.
Any suggestions to fix this problem? Has anyone had this problem before?

This is the code I'm testing:

```html
-- DatePicker.qml
  ...

  property date p_date

  Calendar {
        anchors.fill: parent
        minimumDate: 1950
        maximumDate: 2050
        selectedDate: p_date

        onClicked: {
            p_date=selectedDate
            accepted()
            stack.pop()
        }
    }


-- Form.qml

  ...

  onClicked: {stack.push(id_dialogDate)}
  ...

  Component {
        id: id_dialogDate
        DatePicker {}
  }
```

The expected output when DatePicker is opened should show the Calendar in the correct month with the chosen date highlighted. Say for instance I'm opening the Calendar choosing 22/March/15:

The result is:
![][1]
The Month is correct at the top, but the calendar is really showing February. Look at the last day of the month: 28

Now when I click and jump to the next month, it shows:
![][2]
The month is showing April at the top, but the calendar is really showing March and the date I chose 22/March is highlighted.

Any suggestion?

Note: I couldn't attached the screenshots. The system ask me for 10 reputation points :(.

Comment: Please edit the question and provide a minimal example containing only with the erroneous behaviour. If it is a BUG (so totally unrelated to the phone brand) it could be interest to report it.

Comment: Am I missing something or does this have nothing to do with programming?